Pulling BIM data from
forgive me as I am not very tech savvy but I am trying to find out how I can leverage the Web Viewer to extrapulate the BIM data from a RVT file?  I am trying to run a report from the BIM data from a RVT model and hoping I can speak to someone about doing this?
Murrayenter image description here
We have not tried anything yet as we need some guidance and wondering if there is anything in the SDK?

Here is a quick code sample to dump all the properties from a Revit Model in APS Viewer.


 function getAllDbIds(viewer) {
   var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;

   var allDbIdsStr = Object.keys(instanceTree.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex);

  return allDbIdsStr.map(function(id) { return parseInt(id)});
}

var AllDbIds = getAllDbIds(myViewer);
myViewer.model.getBulkProperties(AllDbIds, null,
   function(elements){
    console.log(elements);//this includes all properties of a node.
 })



For more details, refer the answer at How to get Model object metadata properties in Javascript AutoDesk

Hi Zhong,
How can we get cost-related data using the above functions? I want to implement cost and material-related reports using it. I am using Autodesk 360 viewer SDK. Currently, I am not able to get these data using it.
Thanks

Hi Hardik, is this related to this topic? looks a different question, right?

I think it's related to your function. Do I need to use any other function to get the cost information?
